# Binding data to new elements in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am working with a d3 scatterplot. I connect to my database and initially I begin with lets say 3 dots on the graph. Each dot represents a paper and the x axis is the year and the y axis is how many citations it has. Now when I click on a dot, papers that that paper cites appear on the graph. I have managed all of the above so far but my issue now is that although when I click on dot the relevant papers appear on the graph, when I click on THOSE dots nothing happens. So I havent managed to bind my Json data to the new dots. Here is the relevant code:

```
// initial connection to display papers
d3.json("connection4.php", function(error,dataJson) {

dataJson.forEach(function(d) {

    d.YEAR = +d.YEAR;
    d.counter = +d.counter;
    console.log(d);
    })

//baseData is the original data that I dont want to be replaced
baseData = dataJson;

// draw dots
    var g = svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .data(baseData)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(Num_citationsFn(d))})
        .style("fill","blue") 

.on("click", function(d, i) {

        d3.json("connection2.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error, dataJson) {

            console.log(dataJson);

            dataJson.forEach(function(d) {
                d.YEAR = +d.YEAR;  
                d.counter = +d.counter;
                console.log(d);


                baseData.push(d);
                })

                var g = svg.selectAll(".dot")
                    .data(baseData) 
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "dot")
                    .attr("r", 3.5)
                    .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
                    .attr("cy", function(d) {return  y(Num_citationsFn(d))})
                    .style("fill", "red") 

                    })
```

My queries in the php file are fine as I can see they are returning the correct data, so I think my main issue is binding my Json data from my second connection to the new dots. I wonder can anyone shed some light on how I need to go about this. I am new to d3 so any feedback is appreciated! thanks in advance

Comment: As a general comment to your code, you should try to factorize bits of codes into functions instead of copy-pasting. A function taking a data object and updating your list of nodes would probably have avoided the problem in the first place. I'm also thinking of the formatting lines (`d.YEAR = +d.YEAR; `).

Comment: @laurent thanks I really appreciate your feedback, I am very much a beginner so thats why my code is not as well formed as it should be but will try and utilize functions more as you said as it will probably make my life a lot easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is very simply that you do not bind the `"click"` event to your newly created nodes.

Replace the lines

```
// draw dots
var g = svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(baseData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(Num_citationsFn(d))})
    .style("fill","blue") 
    .on("click", function(d, i) {
     ...
     })
```

by

```
function clickHandler (d,i){
   ...
}

// draw dots
var g = svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(baseData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(Num_citationsFn(d))})
    .style("fill","blue") 
    .on("click", clickHandler); //clickHandler is referenced here, instead of the original anonymous function
```

and add also a `.on("click", clickHandler);` call to your newly created node, i.e. within the clickHandler function itself:

```
           ///add linked dots
           var g = svg.selectAll(".dot")
                .data(baseData) 
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("class", "dot")
                .attr("r", 3.5)
                .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
                .attr("cy", function(d) {return  y(Num_citationsFn(d))})
                .style("fill", "red") 
                .on("click", clickHandler); //click handler is *also* called here
```

Comment: this makes a lot of sense to me. But I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: clickHandler is not defined` when I put `.on("click", clickHandler);` after the closing } bracket of the clickHandler function? @laurent

Comment: Ok, it's probably because I used an anonymous function, these guys don't like recursivity. It's corrected now.

Comment: probably a long shot but thought Id chance it, everything you helped me with was works now I am just trying to use the same method to create a right click handler.The problem seems to be that my Json data is not being bound to the new nodes. But the error Im getting now is:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` and the undefined is dataJson.. which worked fine for the previous click event.. I have tried re naming the data to be passed through but no luck.. dataJson is previously defined so I am unsure where the problem lies! sorry for bringing this up again! @laurent

Comment: Sorry I can't tell without seeing more of the code, and what you've changed . To find out how your data becomes `undefined`: use `console.log(dataJson)` every few lines to find out the faulty line. Once you have it, double check the values of all your variables in this line with more `console.log`s.  Hope this helps :) @John Power